# Apply categorized render to Vector Layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am new to QGIS and I am cannot find a solution to my problem. I have this piece of code:

```
coord_layer = QgsVectorLayer(coords, "my_layer")
single_symbol_renderer = coord_layer.renderer()

symbol = single_symbol_renderer.symbol()

symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255, 0, 0))
symbol.setWidth(3)

coord_layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(coord_layer.id())
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(coord_layer)
```

Which sets width and color to my layer.
However, I would like to use Categorized Renderer and paint my data based on one of my attributes.

How do I change renderer of a layer and perform this task?

Comment: Several answers deal with this matter: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpyqgis%5D+categorized You could try them and ask if your attempts don't work.